# Cannot start Java Flight Recorder or attach Java Mission Control

Tags: java, performance, monitoring, java-module

I was already using Java Flight Recorder with older Java versions, but the the commands to start from command line have changed.
Now I want to start flight recording my Java 14 (14.0.2) application from Java Mission Control (7.1.2+b04). But in JMC an error is thrown as soon as I click on the running JVM *Start Flight Recording...*:

[image]

When I add `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote --add-exports=jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent=ALL-UNNAMED` to run the application the Java application does not start and throws the folling error:

```
Management agent initialization failure: class jdk.internal.agent.Agent not found.
```

When I add `-XX:StartFlightRecording=name=JMC_Default,maxsize=100m` it does also not start:

```
superinterface check failed: class com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy1.$Proxy14 (in module jdk.proxy1) cannot access class org.objectteams.IBoundBase2 (in unnamed module @0x2ff4acd0) because module jdk.proxy1 does not read unnamed module @0x2ff4acd0
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Failure when starting JFR on_create_vm_3
```

I have no idea how to proceed, as I cannot `add-reads` the runtime generated proxy module.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you running, i.e. Oracle JDK, Red Hat etc? Have you built a custom JDK image using jlink? Try java -version

Comment: It is the official Oracle JDK 14.0.2. `java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: I also asked the maintainer of the language if he has a clue as the language uses transformers to weave loaded classes. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=550627

Comment: Could perhaps be this bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8245283. It's been fixed in JDK 15. Can you try out with the EA of JDK 15. http://jdk.java.net/15/ Please let me know if it helps, since it may make a backport higher priority. If not, could you try -Xlog:jfr*=trace and see where it fails. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. It is still the same. I put the logs for both JDK14 and JDK15 into a gist https://gist.github.com/lschuetze/ff570a3c154f1285a16afb20acd42302

Comment: I will need to debug this to see where things go wrong. Most likely it's bytecode related.

Comment: It could also be our side (as we weave every loaded class with ˋIBoundBase2ˋ). Should I prepare something to you to produce the crash?

Comment: Making it not weave classes with prefix com/sun/proxy/jdk does not remove the problem. However, it works when I configure ObjectTeams to only weave classes of my application. So it IS a problem with ObjectTeams weaving system classes. The problem now is to find out which classes.